# Inconsistency between the Markdown preview area and actual output

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, editor

I've noticed that when editing list items, the Markdown preview area will display them spaced out:

[image: Spaced out example]

Whereas the actual output displays it fine:

- List item
- List item
- List item

There seems to be a `margin-bottom: 1em` set on `.wmd-preview ul li, .wmd-preview ol li`, that isn't there in the actual output.

Comment: It's on ".post-text ul li, .post-text ol li" but only for half the value "margin-bottom: 0.5em;"

Comment: Or so it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch. I have pushed a fix to our dev server so the preview and final render are consistent(0.5em for bottom margin). The change will be live after our next production build.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll keep a lookout.

Comment: Hey, I'm observing the same behavior on [metase]. Would you like me to post a separate meta post?